# Error installing gdk-pixbuf for Python on WIndows 10

Tags: python, dll, conda, entry-point, gdkpixbuf

I have tried repeated attempts at installing the library gdk-pixbuf for Python 3.8/3.9 using conda, on a Windows 10 machine, and failed. Any help with fixing this is appreciated.

I get the following error messages and prompts every time:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reinstalling Anaconda and recreating the Python env ("DSML") for Pythin 3.8 and 3.9 did not help. I also tried installing [MinGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) but that may be completely irrelevant. I tried reading about [DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-entry-point-function) entry points but it's all cryptic to me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [channel mixing can cause such errors](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). Make sure `libglib` is installed from Conda Forge. This can force it:

```bash
conda install -n DSML -c conda-forge conda-forge::libglib
```

Also, you may need to install `glib`, not just `libglib`.

```bash
conda install -n DSML -c conda-forge conda-forge::glib
```

If the latter is the case, please post a bug report to [the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/gdk-pixbuf-feedstock).